# Why is it so difficult to study Sum of Squares (SoS) algorithms with degree $d>4$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, lower-bounds, sum-of-squares

In many publications on the computational complexity of **Sum of Squares** (SoS) algorithms, it is typical to study the degree-$4$ relaxation; e.g.

- [Rounding Sum-of-Squares Relaxations](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dsteurer/papers/sosround.pdf)
- [Sum-of-Squares Lower Bounds for Sparse PCA](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06370v2.pdf)

I was curious why this number $4$ seems so crucial here. What is the difficulty of higher order SoS relaxations?

Comment: I don't know that the constant 4 is very special here, it merely represents the 'state of the art'. In some sense degree 2 SoS was the 'state of the art' for a long time as well, and it is of intense interest when degree 2 SoS is optimal and when degree 4 gives improvement. Higher degree would certainly be interesting, but even today we have enough trouble handling the degree 4 case.

Comment: My, possiibly incorrect, understanding is that degree 2 is fairly well understood: some version of random projection rounding is often optimal. Then degree 4 is the lowest even degree that is higher than 2 :). This is the usual game played in mathematics: let's understand the simplest problem that we currently can't solve.